# Spring: Disable caching of template and static files

Tags: spring, spring-boot

While using `Spring Boot v2.6.3`, `Spring v5.3.15` and `Java 17.0.2`,
I put the `devtools` dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

In `application.yml`, I have this:

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  cache:
    type: none
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
```

If I do a change (java, template or static css file), I have to rebuild the project for the new content to appear in the browser.

Is there a way to prevent `Spring` from caching the templates and the static files?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? when using devtools caching is disabled by default.

Comment: IntelliJ, so I understand I have to rebuild the project after Java code changes. Though, during development, I don't need CSS and templates to be chached.

Comment: Intellij needs some additional configuration to automatically (re)build after changes, if not those changes aren't picked up.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to `spring-boot`, by default the template options such as `Thymeleaf` and `FreeMarker` are configured to be cached. It is done in that way because the template parsing don’t need to be reparsed with every request they serve. Even that is useful in production cached templates are not so great at development time. Cached templates will still be in use until you restart the application.

`DevTools` addresses this issue by automatically disabling all template caching. However as you explained it didn't work for you. Therefore I suggest you remove using `DevTools` and use the below mentioned application property.

To disable the caching all you need to do is set a template-appropriate caching property to `false`. I will mention different properties for different templates for disable the caching.

```
FreeMarker          spring.freemarker.cache 
Groovy Templates    spring.groovy.template.cache
Mustache            spring.mustache.cache 
Thymeleaf           spring.thymeleaf.cache
```

By default, all of these properties are set to `true` to enable caching. You can disable caching for your chosen template engine by setting its cache property to `false`.

For testing purpose, just remove the spring configuration you mentioned in your question and just add the following.

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
```

This works for me and if this doesn't work for you then if should be a different problem.

Comment: I tried removing DevTools, but no luck. `spring.thymeleaf.cache` was already in the application.yml file.

Comment: Removing devtools and disable caching won't help. ONe needs to configure Intellij to automatically build and update classes and resources. This way content gets copied to the output folder and devtools can detect/reload that. Else they remain in the source tree.